# Cannot convert value of type 'x' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently attempting to create a user database, with Firestore in Swift 5.

I have created a signup view controller, and I am following the Firestore documentation ([this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects)), in order to store the user data.

---

In a constants file I have stored the following code.

```swift
struct userMap: Codable {
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let email: String?
    let profilePictureURL: String?
    let UserIdentification: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case email
        case profilePictureURL
        case UserIdentification
    }
}
```

And in my signup view controller, I have this code.

```swift
let user = Constants.userMap(firstName: firstName,
                             lastName: lastName,
                             email: email,
                             profilePictureURL: metaImageURL,
                             UserIdentification: docRefID)

do {
    try dbRef.document(docRefID).setData(user)
} catch let error {
    print("Error writing to Firestore: \(error)")
}
```

On the line `try dbRef.document(docRefID).setData(user)` I am getting the error, "*Cannot convert value of type 'Constants.userMap' to expected argument type '[String : Any]' "*

Something I feel is worth adding. In the firebase documentation, it recommends the below.

```swift
try dbRef.document(docRefID).setData(from: user)
```

But, I tried this, and this too and I was just asked to remove `from:`.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an object of the struct `userMap` instead of using a dictionary. You can fix this by creating a dictionary inside the `userMap` struct and providing that dictionary as the parameter. Since your struct already conforms to `Codable` you can create `Data` from object of `userMap` using `JSONEncoder`. Then you can convert the data to a JSON dictionary to use as a parameter. Here the code:

```
struct userMap: Codable {
    //...
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        let data = (try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)) ?? Data()
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]) ?? [:]
    }
}
```

And for the `setData`:

```
try dbRef.document(docRefID).setData(from: user.dictionary)
```

Note: Main struct names capitalized for consistency So, convert `userMap` to `UserMap`.

Comment: Great! Thank you. So that I'm understanding this right. Here's my understanding of that code: You are taking an object, and turning it into JSON (which I should have done to keep things lightweight), then taking that JSON data and using `.mutipleContainers` to split it into the array type? I'm aware that's probably a massive oversimplification, but am I close with that?

Comment: I've added a bit of explanation to my answer, take a look. And it's not `mutipleContainers` it's `mutableContainers`, which is a reading option for son object and just means the object is mutable.

Comment: `struct UserMap: Codable {`
    `var dictionary: [String: Any] {`
        `guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return [:] }`
        `return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]) ?? [:]`
   `}`
}`

Comment: you need to pass the dictionary `try dbRef.document(docRefID).setData(user.dictionary)`

Answer (score 4):

For reference, another reason why someone may see the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'x' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'
```

when working with Firestore's setData command is because they haven't added the line:

`import FirebaseFirestoreSwift`

Comment: You sir just saved the world!